# function handle in MatLab translation to SciLab

Tags: matlab, scilab

We have some MatLab code that includes lines such as:

```
fTE2D = @(x) (0.0049.*WP^2 + 2.4417.*WP).*((y^(2)+x^(2))^(1/2))^(-0.128.*log(WP) - 1.7855)-SecondD;
```

Which we would like to translate to SciLab.  Cannot find reference to `function handle (Matlab @)` in SciLab.

Answer (score 1):

This Matlab instruction creates an "anonymous" functionand stores it in the `fTE2D` variable

In Scilab all functions are variables
you can create a similar function with

```
    function y=fTE2D(x)
      y= (0.0049.*WP^2 + 2.4417.*WP).*((y^(2)+x^(2))^(1/2))^(-0.128.*log(WP) - 1.7855)-SecondD; ;
    endfunction
```

A significative difference however

In Matlab `WP`, `y` and `SeconD` has to be defined **before** the anonymous function 
   is created and their values are stored in the `fTE2D` variable.
With Scilab the `WP`, `y` and `SeconD` value are taken from the calling scope 
   when the function is called.

example

With Matlab

```
>> a=2
>> foo=@() sqrt(a)
>> foo()
    ans =
   1.4142
>> a=4
>> foo()
    ans =
   1.4142
```

with Scilab

```
--> function y=foo(),y=sqrt(a);endfunction
--> a=2;
--> foo()
ans =
    1.4142
--> a=4;
--> foo()
 ans =
    2
```